# PHP mail form being rejected

Tags: php, email, header

I know this is around a bit, but really curious why this sample below would be rejected by like half of providers. Works on Gmail but rejected by my private work server and Hotmail (Hotmail does not surprise me so much).

What is curious to me is with this format I get a nice header with name, subject and everything is formatted good. If I switch it up a little I can get it to come through on my private server and sometimes on Hotmail but then it is always "unknown sender" and the CC starts failing, like it has a bad header...so a bad header seems to send better than a full one?

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "From: ".$agent." <".$email.">\n";
$headers .= "cc: ".$email."\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: Name <info@domain.com>\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
$headers .= "X-Priority: 1\n";
$headers .= "X-MSMail-Priority: High\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: My mailer";
```

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4021#section-2.1.6  try `Cc` instead. depending on how picky the spam filters are, a miscapitalized header can be enough. Beyond that, it's impossible to say WHY, unless hotmail starts spitting out why - which they won't, coz that'd let spammers adjust

Comment: Just funny, I have a devcot/postfix mail server at work I manage, with spamassassin and with a nice formatted header like this it blocks it as well, if I change the header around a bit (mostly the from) breaks the sender to "unknown sender" but it works. Would think with better formatting it would be more apt to work.

Comment: probably better to just use a library like phpmailer or swiftmailer and leave the header generate up to it. you also get far better debug information from both of them than you ever will with `mail()`. mail is a tinkertoy, you need something industrial.